# Cannot Fire Bullets, Program closes

Tags: python, pygame

I'm beginner in Python and working on a space invader game. I want to make the ship fire bullets but when I press the key for firing, no bullets are shot. After multiple presses, the program closes.

AlienGame.py

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf


def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("TemplAReeb's First Game")
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    bullets = Group()
    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

   while True:
        gf.check_events(ship, bullets)
        ship.update()
        bullets.update()
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        screen.fill(bg_color)
        ship.blitme()
        pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(bg_color)
        ship.blitme()
        pygame.display.flip()
run_game()
```

gamefunctions.py

```
import sys
import pygame
from bullet import Bullet
def check_keydown_events (event, bullets):
    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)

def check_events(ship, bullets):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    ship.moving_right = keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]
    ship.moving_left = keys[pygame.K_LEFT]
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type ==  pygame.KEYDOWN:
         check_keydown_events(event, bullets)


def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
    screen.fill(bg_color)
    ship.blitme()
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I'm getting the error that ai_settings in not defined

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Areeb Irfan/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/AlienGame.py", line 32, in <module>
run_game()
  File "C:/Users/Areeb Irfan/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/AlienGame.py", line 19, in run_game
gf.check_events(ship, bullets)
  File "C:\Users\Areeb Irfan\.PyCharmCE2018.3\config\scratches\game_functions.py", line 16, in check_events
check_keydown_events(event, bullets)
  File "C:\Users\Areeb Irfan\.PyCharmCE2018.3\config\scratches\game_functions.py", line 7, in check_keydown_events
new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
NameError: name 'ai_settings' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the full traceback of your exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is coming from this line in `check_keydown_events`:

```
    new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
```

You're trying to pass `ai_settings` to the `Bullet` constructor, but it's not defined in the current `check_keydown_events` function's namespace. Unlike `update_screen`, you're not passing `ai_settings` in as an argument.

You probably need to fix that. You already know how, since you're already passing `ai_settings` to `update_screen` (where it's not currently used, did you perhaps add it to the wrong place?). You just need to extend it to `check_events` and `check_keydown_events`.